# htaccess to index.php only (no subfolders, files etc)

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

Im trying to password protect index.php (or html) file only but can't manage. Subfolders need to be accessed without password...

Something like...

```
<Files "/var/www/clientarea/index.php">

AuthUserFile /var/www/clientarea/.htpasswd
AuthName "Salasanasuojattu sivusto"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/index\.(php|html?)" SECURED

AuthUserFile /var/www/clientarea/.htpasswd
AuthName "Salasanasuojattu sivusto"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      allow,deny
Allow from  all
Deny from env=SECURED
```